# How to change link color when hovering or clicking lavalamp jquery menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lavalamp

I am using LavaLamp script for my horizontal menu

http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/

Active or hovered link is now grey.
I want to change color on hover (or clicked) menu item, to look like this:

http://screencast.com/t/WU02S3jF

HTML:

```
   `<ul class="lavaLamp">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Plant a tree</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ride an elephant</a></li>
    </ul>`
```

Javascript:

```
(function ($) { $.fn.lavaLamp = function (o) {
    o = $.extend({ fx: "linear", speed: 500, click: function () { } }, o || {});
    return this.each(function () {
        var me = $(this), noop = function () { },
        $back = $('<li class="back"><div class="left"></div></li>').appendTo(me),
        $li = $("li", this), 
        curr = $("li.current", this)[0] || $($li[0]).addClass("current")[0];
        $li.not(".back").hover(function () {
            move(this);
        }, noop);
        $(this).hover(noop, function () {
            move(curr);
        });
        $li.click(function (e) {
            setCurr(this);
            return o.click.apply(this, [e, this]);
        });
        setCurr(curr);
        function setCurr(el) {
            $back.css({"left":el.offsetLeft+"px","width":el.offsetWidth+"px"});
            curr = el;
        };
        function move(el) {
            $back.each(function () {
                $(this).dequeue();
            }
        ).animate({
            width: el.offsetWidth,
            left: el.offsetLeft
        }, o.speed, o.fx);
        };
    });
};})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I posted without finishing topic. sorry. I am trying to change javascript, so the <li>'s are gaining "current" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to your css CSS:

```
.lavaLamp li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background: lightblue;
    //anything else you want to add here
}
```

in addition if you want it also to change upon select you should create a class that is added to the link's `li` element when it is selected and removed when another is selected. for example the `abc` class would be added to the selected link `li` element:

```
.abc a {
    color: white;
    background: lightblue;
    //anything else you want to add here
}
```

Comment: I added that class but i want to change class between the <li>'s with javascipt.

Comment: Edited, add the class to the li element instead of the link itself

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing you need to do is change the css background-color:

```
.lavaLampNoImage li.back {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: blue; // change this line to the correct color
    width: 9px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 8;
    position: absolute;
}
```